# Enabling Google Authentication: The redirect URI in the request, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, google-authentication

I want to enable Google Authentication in my web application (ASP.NET Core 3.1).
I got this error:

> The redirect URI in the request,
>   https://localhost:44345/signin-google, does not match the ones
>   authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect
>   URIs, visit:
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/...

How can I solve it?

**I have set the redirect Uri in my console.developers.google.com like this:**

Authorized JavaScript origins

URIs:

https://localhost:44345

Authorized redirect URIs

URIs:

https://localhost:44345/Account/GoogleResponse

[image: Authorized redirect URIs]

- **Startup class > ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  method:**

  ```
  services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(opts =>
      {
          opts.ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
          opts.ClientSecret = "yyy";
      });
  ```

**AccountController:**

```
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {


       [AllowAnonymous]
       public IActionResult GoogleLogin(string returnUrl)
       {
           string redirectUrl = Url.Action("GoogleResponse", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
           var properties = signInManager
            .ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", redirectUrl);
           return new ChallengeResult("Google", properties);
       }

       [AllowAnonymous]
       public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse(string returnUrl = "/")
       {
           // some codes
       }

   }
```

[image: redirect_uri_mismatch]

Comment: `/Account/GoogleResponse` != `https://localhost:44345/Account/GoogleResponse`. Error message should be clean isn't it? Also seems you are using the default value, which is https://localhost:44345/signin-google (when using ASP.NET Core Identity)

Comment: How can I change the default value? I have changed the uri in console already. What should I do extra?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-default-callback-uri

Comment: if I change Authorized redirect URIs to  https://localhost:44345/signin-google, the program run the GoogleResponse method but I got another error. If I cannot solve it, I share it here.